# Superagent request within a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, superagent

I have two kubernetes controllers and services with pods running named `web` and `api` respectively.

In my `web pod` I am using [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent) to try and access an `api pod` with the following `http://api:3000/api/user` this results in the error `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

However if I run a shell on my `web pod` and `curl http://api:3000/api/user` everything works as it should

Am I missing something fundamental about how superagent works? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you launch your superagent in a browser, the browser is not a part of Kubernetes cluster, hence it neither uses kube DNS nor can it access cluster IPs.

To make it work you need to expose your api service to the external world by means of NodePort/Loadbalancer service or Ingress

Comment: I would really prefer not to expose my `api` publicly is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Well, that really depends on what you expect to accomplish. For ad-hoc connectivity you could use `kubectl port-forward` to a deployed api pod. I assume this is some kind of internal tool that you don't want to expose to external world ?